# Can Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server run on windows server 2012 R2?

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, driver

I can't connect to a ODBC on my 2012 R2 server. So i was wondering if i had to install a driver.

I got to this driver: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

It doesn't say that it's compatible on windows server 2012 **R2**.

Does anybody know if it is compatible?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message on your windows server 2012 R2 machine? Can you please show your error message as a text? Since I'm at work now, I can't see it.

Comment: *Remote address could not be resolved* indicates that there is a problem reaching the database server, e.g. that the hostname can't be found. Can you reach the database server from the Windows Server 2012 machine at all?

Comment: @Dirk We now know for sure that it is a driver problem. Please read the question again.